# is there any software that can normalize data base's tables?

Tags: database

i need a free software that can normalize tables and shows the steps it takes.

Comment: Who on earth upvoted and favourited this question?! This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Jonners: db normalizer is one of the jobs programmers sometimes have to do.   not sure if there's a better SE for this question.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Yes, granted, part of the developers' role can include normalisation of database tables. However, this question is not tagged with a specific database RDBMS to help us provide an answer, nor does it have any examples of things already tried (e.g. "I googled for it and got nothing useful") or even samples of the schema that are causing problems. Questions are routinely closed when generic, non-specific queries like this are posted - there's nothing here to indicate that the questioner has made a stab at solving the problem, and little for us to work with to provide an answer...

Comment: @jonners: i googled for it and got nothing useful , i know that i should not ask a question  before i searched the web for it , this question was asked by one of my professors , i have to give the tables of a database to a software that can normalize them and shows the steps it takes ( using 1NF , 2NF , 3NF ...) excuse me if I did not ask my question in good form.

Comment: Well googling for 'Normalisation' gives plenty of hits on the processes involved in taking a schema through First, Second and Third Normal Form. It's pretty straightforward, requiring not much more than the application of a few simple rules. Might want to tag your question as homework, too.

Answer (score 2):

CASE tools of that kind used to be pretty common but are less common today. If you define a set of attributes and dependencies then it isn't difficult to write code to put them into a given Normal Form - the algorithms to do it are well known and straightforward.

However, for most practical purposes such tools are of limited value. Most of the analysis effort needs to be put into identifying the right attributes and desired dependencies in the first place. So actually normalizing them is a fairly simple part of the design process.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as database normalization requires good analysis skills, understanding the problem domain and being able to decide when to stop normalizing (seeing as there is a trade-off between speed and space savings), you are unlikely find a piece of software that will automatically normalize a database.